SSR Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server
Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
main.tsx file - Trying to implement SSR but getting issue for UI mismatch.
import ReactDOM, { hydrateRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from "@tanstack/react-query-devtools";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import AppRouter from "./Navigator/AppRouter.tsx";
import { GlobalProvider } from "./Context/GlobalContextProvider.tsx";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toast";
import "../index.css";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import "react-date-picker/dist/DatePicker.css";
import "react-calendar/dist/Calendar.css";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { AccessTokenProvider } from "@Context/AccessTokenContextProvider.tsx";
import store from "./store/store.ts";
import React from "react";

// Create a new QueryClient instance
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      staleTime: 10000,
    },
  },
});

// Get the root element and ensure it's not null
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
if (rootElement) {
  hydrateRoot(
    rootElement,  // Pass the root element here
    <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
          <GlobalProvider>
            <AccessTokenProvider>
              <AppRouter />
            </AccessTokenProvider>
            <ToastContainer delay={6000} position="top-center" />
          </GlobalProvider>
          <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
        </QueryClientProvider>
      </Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
} else {
  console.error("Root element not found. Unable to hydrate.");
}

AppRouter File - App router file contain All the routes.
import { Navigate, Outlet, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { Suspense, lazy } from "react";
import { AppRoute } from "./AppRoute";
import Preloader from "@Components/Loader";
import ForgotPassword from "@Container/Auth/ForgotPassword/ForgotPassword";
import RejectedJob from "@Container/Dashboard/Container/RejectedJob/RejectedJob";
import AccptedJob from "@Container/Dashboard/Container/AccptedJob/AccptedJob";
import Error from "@Container/Error/Error";
import JobDetailsUpdate from "@Container/JobDetail/JobDetailsUpdate";
import ShareProfile from "@Container/Dashboard/Container/Profile/ShareProfile";

const BlogDetails = lazy(() => import("@Container/Blog/BlogDetails"));
const ChooseTemplate = lazy(
  () => import("@Container/Resume Builder/Choose Template/ChooseTemplate")
);
const ResumeDesignsOne = lazy(
  () =>
    import(
      "@Container/Resume Builder/Resume Designs/Resume-one/ResumeDesignsOne"
    )
);
const Info = lazy(() => import("@Container/Resume Builder/Info/Info"));
const ResumeIndex = lazy(() => import("@Container/Resume Builder/ResumeIndex"));
const ResumeMain = lazy(
  () => import("@Container/Resume Builder/Resume Main/ResumeMain")
);
const Applied = lazy(
  () => import("@Container/Dashboard/Container/Applied/Applied")
);
const Profile = lazy(
  () => import("@Container/Dashboard/Container/Profile/Profile")
);
const DashboardLayout = lazy(
  () => import("@Container/Dashboard/DashboardLayout")
);
const UserDashboard = lazy(
  () => import("@Container/Dashboard/Container/UserDashboard/UserDashboard")
);
const Resume = lazy(
  () => import("@Container/Dashboard/Container/Resume/Resume")
);
const SavedJob = lazy(
  () => import("@Container/Dashboard/Container/SavedJob/SavedJob")
);
const AccountSetting = lazy(
  () => import("@Container/Dashboard/Container/AccountSetting/AccountSetting")
);
const Home = lazy(() => import("../Container/Home/Home"));
// const JobListing = lazy(() => import("@Container/JobListing/JobListing"));
const JobListing = lazy(() => import("@Container/JobListing/FilterJob"));
const Login = lazy(() => import("@Container/Auth/Login/Login"));
const SignUp = lazy(() => import("@Container/Auth/SignUp/SignUp"));
const Layout = lazy(() => import("@Container/Layout/Layout"));
const Membership = lazy(
  () => import("@Container/Dashboard/Container/Membership/Membership")
);
const ApplyJob = lazy(() => import("@Container/ApplyJob/ApplyJob"));
const PublicRoute = lazy(() => import("./PublicRoute/PublicRoute"));
const PrivateRoute = lazy(() => import("./PrivateRoute/PrivateRoute"));
const Thankyou = lazy(() => import("@Container/ThankYou/ThankYou"));
// const Error = lazy(() => import("@Container/Error/Error"));
const ContactUs = lazy(() => import("@Container/contactUs/ContactUs"));
const Subjects = lazy(() => import("@Container/Subjects/Subjects"));
const Aboutus = lazy(() => import("@Container/Aboutus/Aboutus"));
const Faq = lazy(() => import("@Container/Faq/Faq"));
const Termsofuse = lazy(() => import("@Container/Termsofuse"));
const Blog = lazy(() => import("@Container/Blog/Blog"));
const Privacypolicy = lazy(
  () => import("@Container/privacypolicy/Privacypolicy")
);
const RefundPolicy = lazy(() => import("@Container/RefundPolicy/RefundPolicy"));

const AppRouter = () => {
  return (
      <Suspense fallback={<Preloader />}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
            <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
            {/* <Route path="/signin-linkedin" component={LinkedInCallback} /> */}
            <Route path={`${AppRoute.Find_Jobs}`} element={<JobListing />} />
            <Route path={AppRoute.Home} element={<Home />} />
            <Route path={AppRoute.Faqs} element={<Faq />} />
            <Route path={AppRoute.About_Us} element={<Aboutus />} />
            <Route path={AppRoute.Terms_of_use} element={<Termsofuse />} />
            <Route path={AppRoute.Privacy_Policy} element={<Privacypolicy />} />
            <Route path={AppRoute.Contact_Us} element={<ContactUs />} />
            <Route path={AppRoute.Refund_Policy} element={<RefundPolicy />} />
            <Route path={AppRoute.Blog} element={<Blog />} />
            {/* <Route path={AppRoute.Careers} element={<Careers />} /> */}
            <Route
              path={`${AppRoute.Blog}/:title/:id`}
              element={<BlogDetails />}
            />
            <Route path={`:category/:sub_id`} element={<Subjects />} />
            <Route
              path={`${AppRoute.Find_Jobs}/:title/:id/:state/:city/:range/:experience`}
              element={<JobDetailsUpdate />}
            />
            <Route
              path={`${AppRoute.Find_Jobs}/:category/:subjects`}
              element={<JobListing />}
            />
            <Route
              path="/"
              element={
                <PrivateRoute>
                  <Outlet />
                </PrivateRoute>
              }
            >
              <Route path={AppRoute.ResumeIndex} element={<ResumeIndex />}>
                {/* Redirect to Info when accessing ResumeIndex */}
                <Route
                  index
                  element={<Navigate to={AppRoute.Info} replace />}
                />
                <Route path={AppRoute.Info} element={<Info />} />
                <Route
                  path={AppRoute.ChooseTemplate}
                  element={<ChooseTemplate />}
                />
                <Route path={AppRoute.ResumeMain} element={<ResumeMain />} />
                <Route
                  path={AppRoute.ResumeDesignOne}
                  element={<ResumeDesignsOne />}
                />
              </Route>
              {/* Other private routes */}
            </Route>
            <Route
              path="/"
              element={
                <PrivateRoute>
                  <Outlet />
                </PrivateRoute>
              }
            >
              <Route path={AppRoute.ShareProfile} element={<ShareProfile />} />
              <Route path={AppRoute.Thank_You} element={<Thankyou />} />
              <Route path={AppRoute.Dashboard} element={<DashboardLayout />}>
                <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
                <Route path={AppRoute.Profile} element={<Profile />} />
                <Route
                  path={`${AppRoute.User_Dashboard}`}
                  element={<UserDashboard />}
                />
                <Route path={`${AppRoute.Resume}`} element={<Resume />} />
                <Route path={`${AppRoute.Saved_Job}`} element={<SavedJob />} />
                <Route path={`${AppRoute.Applied_Job}`} element={<Applied />} />
                <Route
                  path={`${AppRoute.Accepted_Job}`}
                  element={<AccptedJob />}
                />
                <Route
                  path={`${AppRoute.Rejected_Job}`}
                  element={<RejectedJob />}
                />
                <Route
                  path={`${AppRoute.Account_Setting}`}
                  element={<AccountSetting />}
                />
                <Route
                  path={`${AppRoute.Membership}`}
                  element={<Membership />}
                />
              </Route>
              <Route path={`${AppRoute.Apply_job}`} element={<ApplyJob />} />
            </Route>
            <Route
              path="/"
              element={
                <PublicRoute>
                  <Outlet />
                </PublicRoute>
              }
            >
              <Route path={AppRoute.ShareProfile} element={<ShareProfile />} />
              <Route path={AppRoute.Login} element={<Login />} />
              <Route path={AppRoute.SignUp} element={<SignUp />} />
              <Route
                path={AppRoute.Forgot_password}
                element={<ForgotPassword />}
              />
            </Route>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Suspense>
  );
};

export default AppRouter;

Webpack config file -
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import htmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';

/**
 * Load JS, JSX, TS, and TSX files through Babel
 */
const babelLoader = {
  test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, 
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      presets: [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        '@babel/preset-typescript',
        ['@babel/preset-react', { runtime: 'automatic' }] 
      ],
    },
  },
};

// Common resolve configuration
const resolve = {
  extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
  alias: {
    '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), // Set alias for @
    '@Context': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/Context'),
    '@Assets': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets'),
    '@Container': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/Container'),
    '@Hooks': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/Hooks'),
    '@Navigator': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/Navigator'),
    '@Components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/Components'),
    '@Repo': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/Repo'),
    '@Utils': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/Utils'),
    '@Const': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/Const'),
  },
};

const serverConfig = {
  target: 'node', 
  mode: 'development', 
  entry: './server/server.tsx', 
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'server.cjs', 
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      babelLoader, 
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|webp)$/i, 
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[path][name].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/, 
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader', 
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader', // Adds Tailwind CSS support
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: [
                  require('tailwindcss'),
                  require('autoprefixer'),
                ],
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/, 
        use: [
          'style-loader', // Injects styles into the DOM
          'css-loader',   // Resolves CSS imports
          'sass-loader',  // Compiles SCSS to CSS
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
      PORT: 3001, 
    }),
  ],
  resolve: resolve, 
};

const clientConfig = {
  target: 'web', 
  mode: 'development', 
  entry: './src/main.tsx', 
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), 
    publicPath: '/static', 
    filename: 'client.js', 
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      babelLoader,
      {
        test: /\.css$/, 
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader', 
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader', // Adds Tailwind CSS support
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: [
                  require('tailwindcss'),
                  require('autoprefixer'),
                ],
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/, 
        use: [
          'style-loader', // Injects styles into the DOM
          'css-loader',   // Resolves CSS imports
          'sass-loader',  // Compiles SCSS to CSS
        ],
      },
      // Rule for image files
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|webp)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: '[path][name].[ext]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new htmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, './index.html'), 
    }),
  ],
  resolve: resolve, 
};

export default [serverConfig, clientConfig];

Server.js file
import React from "react";
import express from "express";
import { StaticRouter } from "react-router-dom/server";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import AppRouter from "../src/Navigator/AppRouter";
import fs from "fs";

const app = express();
const PORT = 3001;

/**
 * @param {string} location
 * @return {string}
 */
const createReactApp = async (location) => {
  const reactApp = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <StaticRouter location={location}>
      <AppRouter />
    </StaticRouter>
  );

  const html = await fs.promises.readFile(`${__dirname}/index.html`, "utf-8");
  const reactHtml = html.replace(
    '<div id="root"></div>',
    `<div id="root">${reactApp}</div>`
  );
  return reactHtml;
};

app.use("/static", express.static(__dirname));

app.get("*", async (req, res) => {
  const reactApp = await createReactApp(req.url);
  res.status(200).send(reactApp);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`);
});

Trying to implement SSR on react but getting this issue.

2react-dom.development.js:12507 Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
at throwOnHydrationMismatch (react-dom.development.js:12507:9)
at tryToClaimNextHydratableInstance (react-dom.development.js:12520:7)
at updateHostComponent (react-dom.development.js:19897:5)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21613:14)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27421:14)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26552:12)
at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26461:5)
at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26429:7)
at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25733:74)
at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:266:34)
throwOnHydrationMismatch @ react-dom.development.js:12507
tryToClaimNextHydratableInstance @ react-dom.development.js:12520
updateHostComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19897
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21613
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27421
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26552
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26461
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26429
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25733
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Show 12 more frames
Show less
react-dom.development.js:19844 Uncaught Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.
at updateHostRoot (react-dom.development.js:19844:57)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21610:14)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27421:14)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26552:12)
at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26461:5)
at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26429:7)
at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25845:20)
at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25745:22)
at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:266:34)
at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:239:14)
updateHostRoot @ react-dom.development.js:19844
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21610
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27421
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26552
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26461
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26429
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25845
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25745
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Show 11 more frames
Show less
staticvendors-node_modules_prop-types_index_js.client.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at staticvendors-node_modules_prop-types_index_js.client.js:1:1)
staticvendors-node_modules_react-tabs_esm_index_js.client.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at staticvendors-node_modules_react-tabs_esm_index_js.client.js:1:1)
staticsrc_Container_Layout_Layout_tsx.client.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at staticsrc_Container_Layout_Layout_tsx.client.js:1:1)
2react.development.js:1408 Uncaught ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk vendors-node_modules_prop-types_index_js failed.
(missing: http://localhost:3001/staticvendors-node_modules_prop-types_index_js.client.js)
at __webpack_require__.f.j (client.js:3114:29)
at client.js:2983:40
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
at __webpack_require__.e (client.js:2982:67)
at eval (AppRouter.tsx:82:58)
at lazyInitializer (react.development.js:1358:20)
at mountLazyComponent (react-dom.development.js:19939:19)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21588:16)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27421:14)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26552:12)
__webpack_require__.f.j @ client.js:3114
(anonymous) @ client.js:2983
__webpack_require__.e @ client.js:2982
eval @ AppRouter.tsx:82
lazyInitializer @ react.development.js:1358
mountLazyComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19939
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21588
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27421
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26552
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26461
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26429
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25845
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25745
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Show 12 more frames
Show less
react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in one of your React components:

at Lazy
at RenderedRoute (webpack://fps-web-frontend/./node_modules/react-router/dist/index.js?:577:5)
at Routes (webpack://fps-web-frontend/./node_modules/react-router/dist/index.js?:1267:5)
at Suspense
at AppRouter
at AccessTokenProvider (webpack://fps-web-frontend/./src/Context/AccessTokenContextProvider.tsx?:31:66)
at GlobalProvider (webpack://fps-web-frontend/./src/Context/GlobalContextProvider.tsx?:31:66)
at QueryClientProvider (webpack://fps-web-frontend/./node_modules/@tanstack/react-query/build/modern/QueryClientProvider.js?:28:3)
at Provider (webpack://fps-web-frontend/./node_modules/react-redux/dist/react-redux.mjs?:1053:3)
at Router (webpack://fps-web-frontend/./node_modules/react-router/dist/index.js?:1201:15)
at BrowserRouter (webpack://fps-web-frontend/./node_modules/react-router-dom/dist/index.js?:693:5)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18687
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:18715
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:13923
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:13944
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:23386
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24683
commitLayoutEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24669
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24607
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26818
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26677
finishConcurrentRender @ react-dom.development.js:25887
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25804
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Show 15 more frames
Show less
react-dom.development.js:26918 Uncaught ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk vendors-node_modules_prop-types_index_js failed.
(missing: http://localhost:3001/staticvendors-node_modules_prop-types_index_js.client.js)
at __webpack_require__.f.j (client.js:3114:29)
at client.js:2983:40
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
at __webpack_require__.e (client.js:2982:67)
at eval (AppRouter.tsx:82:58)
at lazyInitializer (react.development.js:1358:20)
at mountLazyComponent (react-dom.development.js:19939:19)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21588:16)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27421:14)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26552:12)
__webpack_require__.f.j @ client.js:3114
(anonymous) @ client.js:2983
__webpack_require__.e @ client.js:2982
eval @ AppRouter.tsx:82
lazyInitializer @ react.development.js:1358
mountLazyComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19939
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21588
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27421
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26552
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26461
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26429
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25845
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25745
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Show 12 more frames
Show less
staticvendors-node_modules_tanstack_query-devtools_build_Devtools_TCDAW7I4_js.client.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at staticvendors-node_modules_tanstack_query-devtools_build_Devtools_TCDAW7I4_js.client.js:1:1)



Are you sure that there is no client side components(use client) inside the SSR page you're rendering?

Its clearly because you are hydrating with All providers but those were not there when you did SSR.
